# sudo startx broke my account

Tags: raspbian, sudo, login

I wanted a font so I placed the `.ttf` in `/usr/local/shared/fonts`

To do this I had to do `sudo startx` to give me super user. Now I wanted to check it worked so I rebooted and it asked me to login even though I have auto login enabled in raspi config. I changed no passwords but cannot log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the ownership of ~/.XAuthority back to user pi. Below is one way of doing this.

If you are stuck at the login screen you can press  to get to a command line login. Log in with the credentials of the user pi (default is pi / raspberry). Once you're logged in use this command to correct the problem:

```
sudo chown pi:pi .XAuthority
```

After this  should get you back to the desktop login, which (hopefully) now accepts your credentials. After a reboot auto-login should also work again.